# In-App Purchases - How can I know who did the charge-back?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, development, app-store-connect

App purchases and in-app purchases can be cancelled with charge-back if you send a message to [iTunes Store Support](http://www.apple.com/emea/support/itunes/contact.html) within a time frame of a few days and provide them a good reason.

I'd like to know if is possible to know what Apple-ID or User did the charge-back.

Take the following behavior of an `User`. (`you` in this case means the app developer):

1. User makes a $99 in-app purchase and receive YYY 'Gold Coins';
2. User buys in-app stuff using the 'Gold Coins' (Potion, cards, whatever);
3. User receives the items and requests a charge-back;
4. Apple accepts the request and gives user the $99 back;
5. Apple informs you that you received a charge-back, but does not specify anything related to user like device's UDID, account or anything;
6. Without user info, you can't remove the in-game items user got through the purchased coins;
7. User shares this behavior with other users;
8. Everyone does the same;

**What will happen? Game/app 'economy' becomes hell and you get nothing.**

So, is there any secret way (or a not so simple to notice option that I've missed somewhere) on iTunes Connect that allows you to know WHO did that so you can act properly by removing the items/cash/whatever (or even temp/perma ban if the behavior continues)?

Comment: As an App developer I must say that the reply of bmike is bunch of BS.
Users will buy Premium in-games and chargeback either by "reporting a problem", contacting "iTunes Support" or directly in their banks and Apple will not inform the game developer under the idiotic argument that they "do not provide costumer data", however all the developer needs is the transaction ID which is not personal data, to know which payment was chargedback. Why do the developer needs to know this? For controlling, revision, tax and even transparency reasons! Apple may simply not pay the developer 50% of their reve

Comment: Question: Will attempting to re-verify the receipt give you any additional information? On a refund, could you attempt to re-verify every receipt you've received in the last 30 days or so? Second, I agree: I'd like to see the transaction/receipt ID when there is a chargeback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not privy to customer details from any of Apple's App stores unless you are selling a subscription and the user opts in to sharing data.

Other than requiring the users to make an account to play and working within Apple's UUID / temporary device ID framework, you have no realistic way to determine who is spending money or who is asking Apple for a refund.

Have your lawyer (or you if you're the business person responsible for agreements) look over the terms and conditions that explain when you do and do not get customer data.

Barring that, you can always open a support ticket with developer support since you are a paid developer to ask them to look into any patterns of unusual sales for your specific application. When there is a problem, I've found them to be very helpful in sorting out what's proper and how to adjust things to fit the App Store rules into your business model.

Comment: So we can contact Apple and ask it to see the customer behavior and try stop the charge-backs if they are made on a regular basis? That's cool,I'll check that out.But as for the in-game items and the economy itself, then it's a lost cause? I mean, it's a card game and with gold coins, the player can purchase items on the `Premium Shop` (potions, bonuses, etc),and acquire cards from the 'premium summoning' (which has a better cards pool, like rare/strong ones).More rare cards on the hands of players isn't a bad thing if we were getting paid for, but this way it's just like we were giving free.

Comment: I suppose you have a choice. You can trust Apple to handle your billing and operate under their rules (and with them deciding which customers are abusive or not) or to handle your own billing and receipts. It's perfectly acceptable to have an app that directs purchases to your system as opposed to using Apple's payment systems.

Comment: If I remind correctly,apps using systems other than Apple's for in-app purchases get rejected as soon as they see it(unless isn't a digital good inside app,like a Pizza Delivery for e.g.).I was reading about the subscription as well (gave me good ideas),but according to what I've read [First game with subscription](http://appleinsider.com/articles/11/11/22/in_app_subscriptions_arrive_for_app_store_games)/[Problems](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2011-11-23/apple-removes-big-fish-s-game-subscription-plan-from-app-store.html?cmpid=yhoo) seems Apple does not allow subscription method for games.Sad

Comment: You can sell digital goods from a website and track customers with your own account. Think Amazon MP3, Amazon Instant Video, HBO, Netflix, Salesforce.com, and many others. There is no blanket ban on selling digital goods, but you do need to read the contract you sign with Apple closely to understand what is allowed and what isn't.

Comment: bmike: No, you cannot use your own purchase method. Amazon even had to remove the ability to purchase things for the Kindle App on iOS -- you could just read things you had already purchased outside the app. You also cannot have a direct/hot link to an e-commerce system outside the iTunes store, or you will be rejected.